# Make Tooltip component display outside of the SideBar Nav using Tailwind CSS, React-Pro-sidebar, React-tooltip

Tags: css, typescript, tailwind-css, sidebar, react-tsx

I have a Sidebar made with Tailwind CSS, React-Pro-sidebar. I have a few Items in the sidebar that i would like the image of the items to have tooltips. I am using react-tooltip for the tooltip and have it currently displaying. My only issue is that is does not show outside of the Sidebar.[SideBar in collapsed state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9y0Gq.png)

I have tried changing the sidebar position and placement but no luck. Also tried different tailwind CSS styling.
[This is the Sidebar with the tooltip in an open state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XItwz.png)

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useAuth } from 'react-oidc-context'
import { JwtHelper } from '../../utils/JwtHelper'
import { Sidebar, Menu, MenuItem, useProSidebar } from 'react-pro-sidebar'
import { InboxArrowDownIcon } from '@heroicons/react/24/outline'
import { Bars4Icon } from '@heroicons/react/24/outline'
import { AdjustmentsHorizontalIcon } from '@heroicons/react/24/outline'
import { ArrowLeftOnRectangleIcon } from '@heroicons/react/24/outline'
import { HomeIcon } from '@heroicons/react/24/outline'
import { Tooltip } from 'react-tooltip'
import 'react-tooltip/dist/react-tooltip.css'

const SideBar = () => {
  const auth = useAuth()

  const { collapseSidebar } = useProSidebar()
  return (
    <Sidebar>
      <div className="space-y-4">
        <nav>
          <Link to="/">
            <Menu>
              <MenuItem
                icon={<Bars4Icon />}
                onClick={() => {
                  collapseSidebar()
                }}
              >
                <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold text-center">OEVis</h1>
              </MenuItem>

              <MenuItem icon={<HomeIcon />}>
                <Tooltip
                  data-tooltip-id="my-tooltip"
                  data-tooltip-content="Home"
                  className="p-0"
                ></Tooltip>
                Dashboard
              </MenuItem>

              <MenuItem
                className="example-container"
                icon={
                  <InboxArrowDownIcon
                    data-tooltip-id="my-tooltip1"
                    data-tooltip-content="About"
                    data-tooltip-place="right"
                    data-tooltip-offset={40}
                    className="w-full"
                  />
                }
              >
                About
                <Tooltip id="my-tooltip1" />
              </MenuItem>

              <MenuItem
                icon={
                  <AdjustmentsHorizontalIcon
                    data-tooltip-id="my-tooltip2"
                    data-tooltip-content="Settings"
                    data-tooltip-place="right"
                    data-tooltip-offset={40}
                    data-tooltip-float
                  />
                }
              >
                Settings
                <span>
                  <Tooltip id="my-tooltip2" />
                </span>
              </MenuItem>
              <div className="border-b-4 border-gray-500 ..."></div>

              <MenuItem
                className="font-bold"
                icon={
                  <ArrowLeftOnRectangleIcon
                    className="h-12 w-12"
                    onClick={() => void auth.signoutRedirect()}
                  />
                }
              >
                {new JwtHelper().decodeToken(auth.user?.access_token).Displayname}
              </MenuItem>
            </Menu>
            <div></div>
          </Link>
        </nav>
        <div className="border-b-4 border-gray-500 ..."></div>
      </div>
    </Sidebar>
  )
}
export default SideBar
```

My App.tsx

```
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './pages/Home'
import './App'
import { useAuth, hasAuthParams } from 'react-oidc-context'
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import LoadingSpinner from './components/LoadingSpinner'
import Layout from './components/layout/Layout'
import BannerConsent from './components/BannerConsent'

const App = () => {
  const auth = useAuth()

  // Automatically sign-in
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!hasAuthParams() && !auth.isAuthenticated && !auth.activeNavigator && !auth.isLoading) {
      auth.signinRedirect()
    }
  }, [auth.isAuthenticated, auth.activeNavigator, auth.isLoading, auth.signinRedirect])

  if (auth.isLoading) {
    return (
      <div
        style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', height: '100vh' }}
      >
        <LoadingSpinner></LoadingSpinner>
      </div>
    )
  }
  if (auth.activeNavigator) {
    return <div>Signing you in/out...</div>
  }
  if (!auth.isAuthenticated) {
    // <></>
    // about:blank
    return <div>Unable to log in.</div>
  }
  if (auth.error) {
    return <div>Oops... {auth.error.message}</div>
  }

  return (
    <Layout>
      <BannerConsent></BannerConsent>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      </Routes>
    </Layout>
  )
}
export default App
```

This is my Layout.tsx

```
import TopBanner from './TopBanner'
import SideBar from './Sidebar'
import Footer from './Footer'
import React from 'react'
import { ProSidebarProvider } from 'react-pro-sidebar'

const Layout = ({ children }: { children: any }) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <TopBanner />
      <ProSidebarProvider>
        <SideBar />
        <main>{children}</main>
      </ProSidebarProvider>
      <Footer />
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
export default Layout
```

I do have other components that make up my page such as the Footer.tsx and Topbanner.tsx.

I have tried to change tooltip position, placement and also tried to get a working tooltip outside of the SideBar. Seems to work fine outside of the sidebar but does not inside the React Pro Sidebar. My expected result is that it should show the the tooltip only when the SideBar is collapsed and the tooltip should be outside out the SideBar so that it is not cropping the text out.

Comment: So I have a couple questions/comments.  1) you have provided a lot of code here, but it will be non-trivial for other folks to get it up and running to help you debug.  Can you provide a working, minimal example of your problem as a CodeSandbox or similar link?  2) In my professional experience, preventing tooltips (or any content) from overflowing its container is often a very intentional feature, and I suspect that in your case, the creators of the sidebar have probably done this on purpose.

Comment: 3)  From a technical standpoint, probably the only thing standing in your way is `overflow: hidden`.  Maybe the sidebar component has a property that would let you disable the `overflow: hidden`, or maybe you will have to hack something together, but I think that if you look through the DOM with the F12 Developer Tools, you will definitely find an element somewhere in the sidebar that has `overflow: hidden`